# Does a trailing "forward slash" have any meaning in a URL?

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?arg1=val1&arg2/
```

The `?` specifies the start of GET values, but does the trailing `/` have any meaning to a URL?

Reason I'm asking is because this is the first time I've tried it on my website, and all my internal links to CSS, images, etc. (which were all relative links to the current directory) didn't work, and so I need to provide the full path to get them to work in case a user types a URL with a trailing `/`.

I'm thinking of writing a rewrite rule to map `index.php/` to `index.php`. Is there any problem with this? Also, is there a way to generalise this to map `anything.php/` to `anything.php`?

Server is Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Some people use trailing slashes to make clear that the url points to (for example) a folder.

**When you want to point to a file, don't use a trailing slash.**

Some Servers are faster when there is a trailing-slashes (when pointing to a folder). But that depends on the implementation.

Comment: That's the "technical" meaning, although not necessarily a "directory" or a "file", but different parts of the URI. Functionally, they are usually the same unless you have some funky rewrite rules which care about trailing slashes.

Comment: Trailing backslashes?

Comment: How can you point to a folder from a file? `index.php?args/folder`?

I'm not purposely trying to use a trailing backslash, I'm trying to make sure all valid user inputs will work. I'm using apache2 - edited the post thanks.

Comment: I am making my first PHP website and after checking it in nibbler.silktide.com the test found that I have those slashes in my URLs after the name of the files (.php) and it says that it is bad, but I don't know how the hell are they there and how to get rid of them.

Comment: @Laokoon I'm aware that you can't point to a folder from a file, I thought that's what your answer was implying. What I'm asking is does the trailing backslash on a URL pointing to a file have any meaning, and is it safe to have a rewrite rule to point it back to the original filename

Comment: It's safe. A File-URI never end with a "/". Imagine there is a file named 'listOfFruits' without an extension. How should the server know, that this is a file, when there is a "/" at the end?. So files are always without "/". Slashes ("/") are for Hierachies.

Comment: @tgun926: Trailing slash doesn't neccessary indicate it's a file or a directory, it may or may not be either. A directory cannot be pointed to a file but there's something called DirectoryIndex, you might wanna learn the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Laokoon's answer is correct, but that's about having a trailing `"/"` (forward slash) at the end of the `"path"` part of the URL, like:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/folder/
```

What you have described in your question is having a trailing `"/"` in the `"query"` part of the URL.

```
Parts of the URL: "http://www.example.com/index.php?arg1=val1&arg2/"
http               Protocol
www.example.com    Subdomain.Domain
index.php          Path
?arg1=val1&arg2/   Query
```

In the case you describe: `"http://www.example.com/index.php?arg1=val1&arg2/"`, the trailing `"/"` does have a meaning, but perhaps not in the way that you might think.

You have tagged your question as [php](/questions/tagged/php), so I will provide a PHP example. It may be handled differently in other languages such as `"Perl"`.

There are 2 possibilities for a trailing `"/"` in the `"query"`:

1) If the trailing `"/"` follows an `"="`, without an `"&"` in between, then the trailing `"/"` is part of the `"value"` of the `"key"` associated with the `"="`:

```
    "?arg1=val1/"            $_GET["arg1"] => 'val1/'
    "?arg1=/"                $_GET["arg1"] => '/'
```

2) If the `"/"` follows an `"&"` (or `"?"`), without an `"="` in between, then the `"/"` is part of the name of a `"key"`. Further, if the `"/"` is at the very end (trailing), then the `"value"` of that `"key"` will be empty:

```
    "?arg1/=val1"            $_GET["arg1/"] => 'val1'
    "?arg1=val1&arg2/=val2"  $_GET["arg2/"] => 'val2'
    "?arg1/"                 $_GET["arg1/"] => ''
    "?arg1=val1&arg2/"       $_GET["arg2/"] => ''
```

If the trailing `"/"` ***immediately*** follows an `"&"` (or `"?"`), then the trailing `"/"` ***is*** the name of a `"key"`:

```
    "?/"                     $_GET["/"] => ''
    "?arg1=val1&/"           $_GET["/"] => ''
```

Here is a **PhpFiddle** example: [querytest2016-0713.php](http://main.xfiddle.com/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/querytest2016-0713.php)

```
<?php

// http://main.xfiddle.com/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/querytest2016-0713.php
echo "querytest2016-0713.php<br>\n";

echo 'HTTP_HOST ="'     . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']    . '"' . "<br>\n";
echo 'REQUEST_URI ="'   . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  . '"' . "<br>\n";
echo 'QUERY_STRING ="'  . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '"' . "<br>\n";
echo "<br>\n";
echo "Test using 'parse_url' and 'parse_str':<br>\n";

// $url = "http://www.example.com/index.php?arg1=val1&arg2/";
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$qry = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($qry);
parse_str($qry, $arr);

echo "url='"   . $url . "'<br>\n";
echo "query='" . $qry . "'<br>\n";

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " => '" . $value . "'<br>\n";
}

echo "<br>\n";
echo "Test using '\$_GET':<br>\n";

foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
  echo $key . " => '" . $value . "'<br />\r\n";
}

?>
```

Example output:
[querytest2016-0713.php?arg1=val1&arg2/](http://main.xfiddle.com/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/querytest2016-0713.php?arg1=val1&arg2/)

```
querytest2016-0713.php
HTTP_HOST ="main.xfiddle.com"
REQUEST_URI ="/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/querytest2016-0713.php?arg1=val1&arg2/"
QUERY_STRING ="arg1=val1&arg2/"

Test using 'parse_url' and 'parse_str':
url='http://main.xfiddle.com/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/ ...
   ... querytest2016-0713.php?arg1=val1&arg2/'
query='arg1=val1&arg2/'
arg1 => 'val1'
arg2/ => ''

Test using '$_GET':
arg1 => 'val1'
arg2/ => ''
```

Example output:
[querytest2016-0713.php?a=111&b=999&c=13579&arg1=901&arg2/=44&argx&whatever/=88&arg3/](http://main.xfiddle.com/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/querytest2016-0713.php?a=111&b=999&c=13579&arg1=901&arg2/=44&argx&whatever/=88&arg3/)

```
querytest2016-0713.php
HTTP_HOST ="main.xfiddle.com"
REQUEST_URI ="/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/querytest2016-0713.php?a=111&b=999&c=13579&arg1=901&arg2/=44&argx&whatever/=88&arg3/"
QUERY_STRING ="a=111&b=999&c=13579&arg1=901&arg2/=44&argx&whatever/=88&arg3/"

Test using 'parse_url' and 'parse_str':
url='http://main.xfiddle.com/55edba50/querytrailingslashtest/ ...
    ... querytest2016-0713.php?a=111&b=999&c=13579&arg1=901&arg2/=44&argx&whatever/=88&arg3/'
query='a=111&b=999&c=13579&arg1=901&arg2/=44&argx&whatever/=88&arg3/'
a => '111'
b => '999'
c => '13579'
arg1 => '901'
arg2/ => '44'
argx => ''
whatever/ => '88'
arg3/ => ''

Test using '$_GET':
a => '111'
b => '999'
c => '13579'
arg1 => '901'
arg2/ => '44'
argx => ''
whatever/ => '88'
arg3/ => ''
```

Of course, if the query string is "manually" parsed in PHP using some other coded method, then the trailing `"/"` may have some other meaning or purpose, or it may be totally ignored.